# Generating 0-10v from 3.3v pin with OP amp problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac, esp32

I'm using this design to generate a voltage 0-10v using the Esp32 DAC

[image]

It was taken from here https://github.com/bdring/Grbl_Esp32/wiki/Spindle-Types and partially works.

Test code I'm using:

```
    while (1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            setup_vfd_speed(i);
            vTaskDelay(1000/ portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

        }
    }

static void setup_vfd_speed(int percentage)
{
    esp_err_t err = ESP_OK;

    if (percentage < 0) {
        percentage = 0;
    }
    else if (percentage > 100) {
        percentage = 100;
    }

    if (percentage == 0)
    {
        // Disable DAC
        err = dac_output_disable(DAC_CHANNEL_1);
        if (err != ESP_OK) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed disabling DAC: %d", err);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Eable DAC
        err = dac_output_enable(DAC_CHANNEL_1);
        if (err != ESP_OK) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed enabling DAC: %d", err);
        }

        // Map percentage to 0-255 scale.
        uint8_t dac_value = ((percentage * 255) / 100);

        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "setting DAC -> : value : %d , percentage : %d", dac_value, percentage);

        // Create a voltage that is propotional to the speed requested
        err = dac_output_voltage(DAC_CHANNEL_1, dac_value);
        if (err != ESP_OK) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed setting DAC output voltage: %d", err);
        }
    }

    // Store the current percentage
    device_state.vfd = percentage;
}
```

The voltage generated works as it should from 10% to 100%. From 0v to 0,3v (aprox) voltage generated by the DAC (or if DAC is disabled) the output is always 10v , any voltage > 0,3v the output voltage is proportional to 0-10v and works as expected. Is there anything wrong with this design?

Note: Even it says 10v in schematic amb using +12v

Comment: Are you definitely using an LM358 op-amp and, where are it's power rails connected?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an LM358 https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Operational-Amplifier_onsemi-LM358DR2G_C7950.html and the power rails are connected pins 4 and 8 in schematic

Comment: If you are seeing 10V regardless the input from the DAC then you should check the connections of the components surrounding the op amp non-inverting amplifier.

Comment: I'm seeing 10v from 0v-0,3v from 0,3v to 3,3v the voltage is scaled correctly

Comment: @Marc sorry, I overlooked that part. Now, here's a question: Why did you connect the pin-4 (VEE) of LM358 to the ground **through a 100n capacitor** instead of directly? I can't see a negative supply voltage so probably the VEE of the chip is floating.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks! that was it. Sometimes you have it right in front of your eyes and still can't see it. It works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the schematic the negative supply pin of the OpAmp LM358 (pin 4) is NOT connected to GND, but in series to a capacitor leading to GND. If this is really the case it can't work.

The capacitor is supposed to be between positive supply (+10V, pin 8) and negative supply (GND, pin4 ).